# Java Hibernate save entity failed on Sql Server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, hibernate

I'm creating a simple Java application using Hibernate 4.1.9.
I can retrieve data from the database, but when I try to insert new records they don't appear in the table and I get an error I can't figure out.

Here is the output :

```
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.9.Final}
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: org/mine/hibernateproject01/UserEntity.hbm.xml
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver] at URL [jdbc:odbc:MySqlServer]
févr. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=, password=****}
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
févr. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
feb. 24, 2013 10:01:52 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:1750)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at $Proxy4.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:105)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:103)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$InsertSelectDelegate.prepare(IdentityGenerator.java:137)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:55)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2936)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3447)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:756)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:748)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:744)
at org.mine.hibernateproject01.App.main(App.java:31)
```

Here is the code

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();    
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        UserEntity u = new UserEntity("name","firstname");

        session.save(u);       <== error occur here
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(tx!=null){
            tx.rollback();
        }
        System.err.println(e);
    } finally{
        session.close();             
    }
    sessionFactory.close(); 
}
```

Here is the hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:odbc:MySqlServer</property>
    <property name="connection.username"></property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>-->
    <mapping resource="org/mine/hibernateproject01/UserEntity.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And here is the UserEntity class and configuration :

```
public class UserEntity {

    private int UserID;
    private String UserName;
    private String UserFirstName;


    public UserEntity(){

    }

    public UserEntity(String UserName, String UserFirstName) {
        this.UserName = UserName;
        this.UserFirstName = UserFirstName;
    }   

    public int getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    public void setUserID(int UserID) {
        this.UserID = UserID;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String UserName) {
        this.UserName = UserName;
    }

    public String getUserFirstName() {
        return UserFirstName;
    }

    public void setUserFirstName(String UserFirstName) {
        this.UserFirstName = UserFirstName;
    }    
}

<hibernate-mapping package="org.mine.hibernateproject01" schema="dbo">
    <class name="UserEntity" table="T_USERLIST" lazy="false">
        <id name="UserID" column="UserID" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>

        <property name="UserName" column="UserName" type="java.lang.String" length="50" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="UserFirstName" column="UserFirstName" type="java.lang.String" length="50" not-null="true"/>        

    </class>    
</hibernate-mapping>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Any advice or help on this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You cut the logs right when it becomes interesting. What's the complete stack trace of the exception? Also, please respect the standard Java naming conventions, and consider using annotations for the mapping instead of the old, obsolete XML mapping files.

Comment: Actually I have nothing else in the output. I'll try the annotations.

Comment: Don't do `System.err.println(e);` Do `e.printStackTrace();` to get the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I edited the first post and added the full stack trace in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver, which is an extremely old JDBC driver, built when JDBC was created more than 10 years ago in order to provide an way to use JDBC with databases which didn't have JDBC drivers yet, but had an ODBC driver. This driver is completely obsolete now. Use a real JDBC driver for SQL Server instead.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx

Comment: You nailed it ! I replaced the driver by net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver and now it works well. Thank you.